# Can NSubstitute's DoNotCallBase() be cleared/reset?

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I created a "partial" mock, and used [`DoNotCallBase()`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/) so my mock method is called rather than the actual method.

Since I need to do this many times in a test fixture, I did it once on setup.

But for one test I need the real method, not the mock. Can I undo/clear the "DoNotCallBase"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible with NSubstitute (v2.0.3). I have created [issue #309](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/309) for this. Please feel free to add to the issue description there. Do you need to be able to undo an single `DoNotCallBase`? Or would it be sufficient to clear every `DoNotCallBase` on the substitute?

Comment: I realise it would be easier to simply clear all of them, but in reality this would only be useful if you could clear one in particular. You'd be building up a mock, and there's that one `DoNotCallBase` which is the problem. If you'd clear all, then you'd need to build up the mock from scratch, so there's no benefit...